# Disjointed rollovers, but each image needs a link

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Long ago, in Adobe GoLive, there was a JavaScript action to create disjointed rollovers, *and* to change what each image was linked to when it changed...
We were  using it to display covers of magazine backissues (on http://www.radford.edu/rumag/pages/backissues.html), by year, then link to the specific issue.
(mouseover 2009, see it's covers, click to them, mouseover 2010, see it's covers, click to them, etc.)

With GL not supported, we've ditched it & moved on to Dreamweaver, but I have no way to add new items to that page, and the original page has gotten corrupted along the away, as well, and isn't working.

I'm looking for a new solution, js/jQuery, or CSS driven, no PHP, to duplicate that.

Comment: Can you define "disjointed rollovers" for us?  I'm not sure what you're trying to get.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve but I'll give it a try.

You can use jQuery data to store information about the urls for the covers as well
as the links (id of each year link is y):

```
  $(document).ready({
    $('#y2010').data('imageurl', 'http://url.to/image.jpg');
    $('#y2010').data('linkurl', 'http://url.to/issue');
  });
```

When the user is hovering a link, load the data

```
$('#y2010').hover(function(){
    $('#<cover image id>').attr('src', $(this).data('imageurl'));
    $('#<issue link id>').attr('href', $(this).data('linkurl'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Oscar, that looks like it's going the right direction, at least.
I'll look at it later today when I have a chance.